# how to connect outbound message to external web service

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, salesforce, apex-code

I'm trying to test out a simple outbound message workflow that will insert a contact record into an external database when the contact is created in Salesforce.

I've created my web service using (C#.NET) VisualStudio 2008 and have tested it successfully directly from the browser from my localhost URL.  So, the web service works and inserts the values I pass into the method and insert into my database.

I've also created the workflow in my salesforce development org with the outbound message action.  I'm pointing the EndPoint URL value to the localhost URL of my web service.

If I understand correctly, I need to create a listener so that when the workflow fires and sends the outbound message, my web service knows what to do.  This is where I'm stumbling.

Can anyone help on how to make that connection?  How do I create the listener and make the handshake between the outbound message and the web service?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

There are is a comprehensive example in [Creating an Outbound Messaging Notification Service with CSharp and .Net Framework 2.0](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Creating_an_Outbound_Messaging_Notification_Service_with_CSharp_and_.Net_Framework_2.0)

This important parts are:

1. Export the outbound message WSDL and have your web service implement the interface. It will be `SomethingSomething.INotificationBinding`
2. Have your web service return an ACK on successful processing or a NACK if there is an error or exception.
3. Ensure your web service is exposed on a public IP address. Salesforce will need to be able to call it.
4. As above, add your web service to the Remote Sites so that Salesforce is allowed to call out to it.

Incidentally, [salesforce.stackexchange.com](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com) is a great place to ask Salesforce specific questions.